# Count rows by grouping

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm trying to get a number row indicator grouped by variable to use as one keyid to join to a later data set.

```
library("tidyverse")

x<- c("age", "credit", "vehicle_age", "rba", "rba", "rba")
x1 <- c(6, 27, 28, 2199, 20130, 30000)
df<- cbind(x, x1)
```

This was the code I was using to try and accomplish this:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(x, x1) %>% mutate("segment" = count(x1))
```

this is the error I get:

`Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'character')"`

This is ultimately what I want it to look like.

```
x1              x2    segment
age             6     1
credit          27    1
vehicle_age     28    1
rba             2199  1
rba             20130 2
rba             30000 3
```

Comment: Did you mean to `group_by(x, x1)` instead?

Comment: Yes.  I have edited the question.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because `dplyr` works with data frames, not matrices. To get each group to sequence up to the total number in the group, use the `n()` function:

```
df %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(segment = 1:n())
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use count.

```
df %>% data.frame %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(segment = row_number())
```